# How do I print or expose a view field value in a page template?

Tags: views, theming

I have a view display (as page) in which I want to theme the full container of the "view", taking the "filter field value of items" as an extra title for the main container. I have tried different preprocess way to get the field out of the view without success.

This is an example of the code I used.

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables)  {
  if ($view_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id') && $view_id === 'viewnamedisplay') {
    $variables['field_to_print'] = $variables['view_id']->$variables['field']->field_to_print->value;
  }
}
```

Then I used `{{ field_to_print }}` in  page--template.html.twig.